# Minor ticks not evenly spaced/aligned with major ticks when setting xlim

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting some timeseries data. I noticed that when plotting the whole timeseries the minor ticks (for the x-axis) are perfectly evenly spaced. But when I set the x-axis limits (`xlim`), suddenly the minor ticks start getting more and more off-sync.

As you can see the minor ticks are perfectly evenly spaced between 2017-01 to 2017-04, but at 2017-07 it is slightly off, then it gets worse at 2017-10 and onwards.

Code and figure:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.xlim(datetime(2017, 1, 1), datetime(2019, 1, 1))
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.plot(df['Date'], df['Price'])
```

[image: pyplot of timeseries with focus on x-axis minor ticks being off]

Is there any way to get the minor ticks perfectly spaced? The number of ticks is not that important, just that they are evenly spaced. I don't care about the y-axis for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Redox I was able to come up with a solution:

```
from matplotlib.dates import MonthLocator, YearLocator

plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.xlim(datetime(2017, 1, 1), datetime(2019, 1, 1))
plt.minorticks_on()

is_label_year = re.match('^\d{4}$', plt.gca().xaxis.get_majorticklabels()[0].get_text())
plt.gca().xaxis.set_minor_locator(YearLocator() if is_label_year else MonthLocator())

plt.plot(df['Date'], df['Price'])
```

Basically, I conditionally set `YearLocator` or `MonthLocator` depending on if the majorticklabels are on the format `YYYY` or `YYYY-MM` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You can acheive that by adding just the minor locator (`set_minor_locator`) to your code and set it to month, which will give minor ticks for each month. Updated sample code with random Price below...

```
Price = {'Price':np.random.randint(30, size=(20))}
df = pd.DataFrame(Price)
df['Date'] = pd.date_range(start = '2017-01-01', end = '2019-01-01', periods = len(df))

plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.xlim(datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1), datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1))
plt.minorticks_on()

## Add these lines
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
plt.gca().xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.MonthLocator()) ## Minor ticks every month

plt.plot(df['Date'], df['Price'])
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This works great between 2017-19. But do you perhaps know how I can get evenly spaced minor ticks dynamically when the date range varies? For example, it can be as large as 2000-2023 as well, and then having a minor tick each month is too cluttered

Comment: You can change the `mdates.MonthLocator()` in the code to `mdates.YearLocator()` if the ticks are too many. Does that solve your problem? Details and options are available [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html)

Comment: `mdates.YearLocator` could potentially be useful. The problem is that I can't beforehand know what date range I have, and therefore can't know which of `MonthLocator()` and `YearLocator()` will be best.

Comment: I'm surprised the default settings of matplotlib doesn't do a better minor tick alignment/spacing than this...

Comment: You are setting `plt.xlim(...)` to a number. If it is changes so much, how are you setting it?

Comment: Sorry you are correct, maybe I expressed myself wrong. What I mean is that in the current graph above we can see that it displays: 2017-01, 2017-04, 2017-07 etc. In other words the major tick "label" is each 3rd month. But that is something Matplotlib does automatically. If I were to have a larger daterange, major tick label will instead be each year or second year.
i.e. the major tick label varies between year and 3rd month and I don't know how to programmatically detect which it is.

Comment: To GET the major ticks, you can use `get_majorticklabels()`, which will get you the labels. With this you can figure whether it is weeks/month/years and then set your minor ticks. An example to get major ticklabels is [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/matplotlib-axis-axis-get_majorticklabels-function-in-python/)

Comment: Thank you Redox you have provided me with all the steps necessary to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `set_major_locator` and `set_minor_locator` with `MultipleLocator` or `AutoLocator` modules from `matploltib`.

```
from datetime import datetime
from matplotlib.ticker import (MultipleLocator, AutoMinorLocator)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
plt.xlim(datetime(2017, 1, 1), datetime(2019, 1, 1))
axs.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(90))

# For the minor ticks, use no labels; default NullFormatter.
axs.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(9))
```